# findMin lazy deletion binary search tree

Tags: java, recursion, data-structures

I found this code for findMIn method in lazy deletion for binary search tree. First of all, is this method correct? If it is can someone explain it to me please.

```
private BinaryNode<AnyType> findMin( BinaryNode<AnyType> t )
{
if (t == null) return null;

BinaryNode<E> tmp= findMin(t.left); // get minimum from the left node

if (tmp != null) return tmp; // if mimimum is not null return minimmum

if (!t.deleted) return t; // if minimum is null in left node and t is not deleted
// return t then

return findMin(t.right); // if t is deleted and minimum of left node of t is null, then search in right side

}
```

I rewrote it to include the following but it is not working.

```
 private BinaryNode<AnyType> findMin( BinaryNode<AnyType> t)

      {
      ArrayList<BinaryNode<AnyType>> trv = new ArrayList<BinaryNode<AnyType>>();

         return findMinVal(t, trv);
      }
private BinaryNode<AnyType> findMin( BinaryNode<AnyType> t, ArrayList<BinaryNode<AnyType>> trv )

     {
             if(t == null) {
                 return t;
             } else {
                 BinaryNode<AnyType> left= findMin(t.left);
                 if(!t.deleted) {
                     trv.add(t);
                 }
                 BinaryNode<AnyType> right= findMin(t.right);

                 return trv.get(0);
             }
```

Comment: This question is duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48895238/how-to-write-findminimum-of-a-lazy-deleted-binary-search-tree-in-java

Comment: please take a look now.

Comment: Can you give an example for which it is not working, I have tried with one example and it seems to be working.

Comment: it threw an index out of range error

Comment: its the second code that is not working

Comment: What is `trv` over here , I am assuming it is an arraylist kind of structure that you have declared globally ?

Comment: It's not, its from a helper function. I edited the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may throw java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException, if while doing `trv.get(0)` arraylist `trv` size is 0.

In order to avoid it you can check that if size of `trv` is not 0 then you can return first element of this list else return null inside `findMin` function

Here is the updated code:

```
private BinaryNode<AnyType> findMin( BinaryNode<AnyType> t, ArrayList<BinaryNode<AnyType>> trv )

     {
             if(t == null) {
                 return t;
             } else {
                 BinaryNode<AnyType> left= findMin(t.left);
                 if(!t.deleted) {
                     trv.add(t);
                 }
                 BinaryNode<AnyType> right= findMin(t.right);

                 return trv.size()==0 ? null :trv.get(0);
             }
     }
```

As, an improvement instead of returning `BinaryNode<AnyType>` from `findMin` function you can return void since anyhow your result is stored in `trv` arrylist and instead of checking everytime `return trv.size()==0 ? null :trv.get(0);` inside `findMin` function (this will be checked for every recursive call), you can check only once inside helper function.

Here is updated optimized code:

```
  private BinaryNode<AnyType> findMin( BinaryNode<AnyType> t)

      {
      ArrayList<BinaryNode<AnyType>> trv = new ArrayList<BinaryNode<AnyType>>();

         findMinVal(t, trv);
         return trv.size()==0 ? null :trv.get(0);
      }

private BinaryNode<AnyType> findMin( BinaryNode<AnyType> t, ArrayList<BinaryNode<AnyType>> trv )

     {
             if(t!=null) {
                 findMin(t.left);
                 if(!t.deleted) {
                     trv.add(t);
                 }
                 findMin(t.right);
             }
}
```

In the above orignal code two if condition are there :

`if (tmp != null) return tmp;` This is used for printing the returned value since we are not using arraylist kind of data structure in orignal code to store the result so as soon as we get result from `findMin` recursive call which is not null we are returning it.

`if (!t.deleted) return t;` This is used for same reason as it is used by your code as `if(!t.deleted) {trv.add(t)}`i.e. we are checking if findMin(left) returned `null` and if its root node is not deleted then return that node since it will smaller than this root node right childrens and hence no need to check further.

But, there is no use of `if (tmp != null) return tmp;` since anyhow each time we will go to 
`if (!t.deleted) return t;` and from there as well result can be returned . So this `first if` can be removed.

Comment: thank you! this is helpful. Can you also explain the original code up there? I don't understand the two if conditions. I just want to know why it's working for the sake of my own learning.

Comment: Have edited my answer to explain the same. Please ask if your issue is not clear.

Comment: @user11452926 If your issue is resolved can you please accept and up vote the answer.